# Show that only finitely

Tags: combinatorics

Call a point in the Cartesian plane with integer coordinates a $lattice$ $point$. Given a finite set $\mathcal{S}$ of lattice points we repeatedly perform the following operation: given two distinct lattice points $A, B$ in $\mathcal{S}$ and two distinct lattice points $C, D$ not in $\mathcal{S}$ such that $ACBD$ is a parallelogram with $AB > CD$, we replace $A, B$ by $C, D$. Show that only finitely many such operations can be performed.

attemp: $\sum_{1\le i<j\le n} \overline{A_i A_j}^2\in\mathbb{N}$ strictly decreases, but since $S$ is a finite set of lattice points, but it has to be at least $\binom{n}{2}$, where $|S|=n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O$ be the midpoint of $ACBD$ and let $X$ be any lattice point. Then, by Pythagoras,
$$AX^2+BX^2=2OX^2+\frac{1}{2}AB^2$$ and so $$CX^2+DX^2<AX^2+BX^2.$$

Therefore your idea works and the process must end.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is good and should work. You just need to prove that while the term from the diagonal of the parallelogram strictly decreases, the other terms don't increase. But in proving this you'll find that the same proof also works for the simpler function $\sum_{1\le i\le n}\|A_i\|^2$.